# how to connect AWS elastic beanstalk to RDS and keep database alive in production

Tags: sql-server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am setting up my django project in AWS elastic beanstalk, and I also setup a separate RDS  instance (sql-server). I am able to ssh in to the VM and connect to the database as I did in development using localhost. How should I keep the database connection alive all the time ?

I am using unixODBC, freetds currently as I did in my development. Should I be different in production?

Thanks a lot of the help.